# What does total connections mean in stats command mean

Tags: memcached

I found that it is way less than total number of get commands. Is this number of server to server connections that are reused.

Answer (score 2):

Total connections is the number of connections that have been made to the server since you started it. Current connections is the number of connections that the server currently has. Total connections should be way less than the total number of get commands because typically you connect to memcached and send multiple get/set requests over the same connection.

Comment: Thanks; is the decision to pool/reuse connection made by the client library logic/code?

Comment: That depends on the client. In spymemcached for example you will need to pool connections yourself. Reusing connections is recommended no matter what library you use.